# Increment variable value by 1 (shell programming)

Tags: shell, debugging, variables, ubuntu, command-line

I can't seem to be able to increase the variable value by 1. I have looked at [tutorialspoint's *Unix / Linux Shell Programming* tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-basic-operators.htm) but it only shows how to add together two variables.

I have tried the following methods but they don't work:

```
i=0

$i=$i+1 # doesn't work: command not found

echo "$i"

$i='expr $i+1' # doesn't work: command not found

echo "$i"

$i++ # doesn't work*, command not found

echo "$i"
```

How do I increment the value of a variable by 1?

Comment: assignments to variables won't have the leading `$` character on the LHS of the expression.

Comment: [How to increment a variable in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/385528/253474)

Comment: for the expr one, it's not working because they have to be backticks ( ` ) rather than single quotes ( ' )

Comment: (`only shows how to add together two variables` - well, they show assignment of a sum of literals: `val=\`expr 2 + 2\``.)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You can use an [arithmetic expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Expansion.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) like so:

```
i=$((i+1))
```

or [declare](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#:%7E:text=declare) `i` as an integer variable and use the `+=` operator for incrementing its value.

```
declare -i i=0
i+=1
```

or use the [`((` construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html).

```
((i++))
```

Comment: The first variant also works in dash (which is sh on many systems). The two others do not.

Comment: The two others are not POSIX compliant - I think they are bash only.  So stick to the first one for maximum portability.

Answer (score 12):

The way to use expr:

```
i=0
i=`expr $i + 1`
```

The way to use i++ (unless you're running with [`-e`/`-o errexit`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/man-pages/set.1p.en#e)):

```
((i++)); echo $i;
```

Tested in gnu bash.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `bc` as it can also do floats

```
var=$(echo "1+2"|bc)
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the methods I know:

```
ichramm@NOTPARALLEL ~$ i=10; echo $i;
10
ichramm@NOTPARALLEL ~$ ((i+=1)); echo $i;
11
ichramm@NOTPARALLEL ~$ ((i=i+1)); echo $i;
12
ichramm@NOTPARALLEL ~$ i=`expr $i + 1`; echo $i;
13
```

Note the spaces in the last example, also note that's the only one that uses `$i`.